# Why do ascetic devotees of Shiva smoke weeds?

Tags: shiva, sanyasi

What is the reason behind ascetic devotess of Shiva particularly Naga Sadhus smoke weeds ? Why do they do so ? Is it some kind of Prasad of Shiva ?

Comment: A good explanation can be found at Chapter 6 under title intoxicants in the book Aghora At the Left Hand of God by Robert Svoboda!

Comment: Prāṇatoṣaṇītantra, a Tāntrika compendium composed around 1820s described the use of smoking cannabis leaves to suppress hunger. Scientific analysis proved that THC, a compound found naturally in cannabis plant can truly suppress hunger to some extent by affecting the release of a hunger-stimulating hormone called ghrelin. However the effect of THC isn't observed universally & can be quickly counteracted by the action of other cannabinoids. Suppression of hunger by people who live upon alms is indeed a good strategy for coping up with the lack of food.

Comment: @river [here](https://cloudflare-ipfs.com/ipfs/bafykbzacedztesysob56a5s3u5uxk4s2krevwsleldeeikswzjiuwcwxpllrm?filename=Robert%20E.%20Svoboda%20-%20Aghora_%20at%20the%20left%20hand%20of%20God-Brotherhood%20of%20Life%20%281986%29.pdf) is the link to the book if you are interested.Sorry i forgot to post the link earlier!